# Why imported geometry from JSONLoader to THREE.js is only displayed if added to the scene inside loader.load callback function?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a three.js code that imports a geometry from blender and displays it on three.js. In order to effectively display it I must add the mesh to the scene inside the loader callback function.
This works:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
var testGeometry; //global variable
loader.load( "sample.js", function( geometry ) {
        testGeometry= new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffcaff, specular: 0x505050, shininess: 100 } ) );
    scene.add( testGeometry);
} );
```

As `testGeometry` is a global variable, I'd expect that the following code would also work fine:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
var testGeometry; //global variable
loader.load( "sample.js", function( geometry ) {
    testGeometry= new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffcaff, specular: 0x505050, shininess: 100 } ) );
    } );
scene.add( testGeometry);
```

But it doesn't. I need to add this mesh to another Object3D further along in my code and then add it to the scene. Any ideas on how to make it work? I think I'm missing something really basic here about global variables and callbacks...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work in the second example is because the callback is executed asynchronously only **after** the file is loaded. When you call `load` the callback is not executed immediately and load does not block until it is finished. As a result when you call `scene.addGeometry`, `testGeometry` has not yet been initialized so you are passing an `undefined` value to it.

In your first example it works because the `.addGeometry` call is being executed from inside the callback.

If you are just going to add it to the scene it would be easier to just scope it inside the callback rather than have to deal with a possibly uninitialized global elsewhere in your code:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( "sample.js", function( geometry ) {
    var testGeometry = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffcaff, specular: 0x505050, shininess: 100 } ));
    scene.add( testGeometry);
});
```

**Edit 1** Promises

One common way to handle a situation like this is to use `Promises` which are standard in ES6 and can be polyfilled easily with libraries like `Q` or `Bluebird`.

*Note* Here I am ES6 specification for promises, most libraries should be compliant with this syntax:

```
var geometryPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  loader.load("sample.js", function(geometry) {
    resolve(new THREE.Mesh(geometry, phongMaterial));
  });
});

//Now your value can never be undefined
//The then handler only gets executed when the promise is resolved.
geometryPromise.then(function(geo) { scene.addGeometry(geo); });
geometryPromise.then(/*Do more stuff it will use the same value*/);
```

Comment: Thanks  for the answer. I'll look for ways of waiting for that callback to be executed before I set some variables which depend on that mesh.

Comment: @8fhg0 Personally I would recommend looking at using promises which would let you do things like `testGeometry.then(/*Handle result*/)` which would only be executed when the value has been loaded. I'll update this with an example.

Comment: I tested your suggestion using promises and it worked just fine! Thanks for your help!